# Can std::cin fail to pass a user input in the command line to a variable with a type of char?

Tags: c++, unicode, cin, non-ascii-characters, text-extraction

I have tried passing different inputs with the below code, but have failed to get the message printed: "Oops, you did not enter an ASCII char, let alone one that is y or n!" I have entered various Unicode characters which are not of char type (basically justed punching in ALT+random numbers, e.g. ™, š, ², Ž, ±. None of these produced the error. Does cin silently ignore or discard inputs that are not ASCII characters?

```
std::cout << "Would you like to play again? Enter y or n: ";
std::cin >> yOrN;
isChar = std::cin.fail();
//check if the user did not enter an ASCII char, e.g. test with a Unicode character
if (isChar)
{ 
    std::cout << "Oops, you did not enter an ASCII char, let alone one that is y or n!\n";
    std::cin.clear();
}
```

OS: Windows 10 64 bit, x64-based processor
Compiler: Visual Studio Community 2015

I was not able to resolve this problem through searching for "extract a non-ASCII character cin C++" and looking at the first three pages.

I'm very new on Stack Overflow, so forgive me if I have violated any rules or code of conduct with this question. I'm learning C++ on learncpp.com and am writing my own code to answer question 2 of this [page](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/5-x-chapter-5-comprehensive-quiz/#comment-286676).

Update: I guess there is no reason for my program to validate whether a char is entered. However, I guess maybe I was so curious to know that I did not think too much about whether it was actually necessary for the program.

Answer (score 1):

`std::cin.fail();` will return true if the underlying stream failed reading or writing data. it has nothing to do with the encoding you provide.

It is also worth mentioning that `char` is not really aware of utf-8 or ASCII, it's just a byte. neither does C++ streams validate the data's encoding.

So in this case, `Ž` (and others) is a valid input for `std::cin`.

If you want to validate ASCII only characters, you need to do it yourself:

```
std::cin >> c;
if (c < 0 || c > 127) { /*handle non ASCII chars*/  }
```

In your case, you need to validate against `y` or `n`:

```
std::cin >> c;
if (c != 'y' && c != 'n') { /*handle invalid input*/  }
```

Comment: plain `char` will never exceed 127 on common systems

Comment: @M.M what if `char` is actually unsigned?

Comment: what if it isn't though? OP said MSVC++ 2015.

Comment: Thanks @DavidHaim. Is there anything that is not a valid input for std::cin?

Comment: What I mean is, is there anything that will fail to extract to a char?